# EXCEPTION: Update is unnecessary as statistics is up-to-date

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

Does it exists any way to change the U-SQL's behavior? I would like if it can ignore silently any statistics that is up to date instead of throw an exception. The reason why i need it. I just wanna schedule triggering of update the stats from ADF. (I would like to have a temporary solution like set @opt='cryptic__undocumented_option')

[image]

Comment: The technical support team has provided me the info: the policy will be changed to warn and skip any updated statistics instead of throw the exception. They plan to deploy the change at the end of the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering explicitly to have an answer appear.

This will be fixed in the upcoming refresh. It was a regression that was introduced by another bug fix. We have now put regression tests into place.

Thanks for reporting!